# Replicate index from master at specific time in Solr 7

Tags: solr, replication

I have a use case where we have a Solr master that is replicated to three replicas in a cluster, and is also replicated to a separate replica in Hong Kong. We were initially replicating all of them every 00:01:05, but that's too much to do at once for network traffic. For the sake of data continuity on the front end, I still need to replicate the three in the cluster simultaneously, and I want to replicate to the HK index separately so when it replicates, it's not doing it at the same time as the three in the cluster.

My question has to do with setting when this happens. From everything I've read, you can only set `pollInterval`, which, as its name indicates, is a frequency. What I'd like to do is similar to what can be done with a *nix cron job, where you can set it to run at a specific time after the hour. So for instance, I'd like to have the cluster replicas do their replication at :05, :15, :25, :35, :45, and :55 every hour, and the HK index to replicate at :00, :10, :20, :30, :40, and :50. Is there a way to do that somehow with `pollInterval`, or perhaps another slave replication handler setting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think Solr supports natively the kind of scheduling that you are looking for. You might be able to do something like it by kicking of the replication [via the Solr API](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_0/index-replication.html#http-api-commands-for-the-replicationhandler) through a cron job.

Comment: Yeah, I'm seeing the same thing.